# How to prevent other QR code scanners from scanning my QR code

Tags: c#, android, image-processing, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a library in `C#` which helps me to generate a QR code and an `android Decoder` which decodes the QR code for me.

**My problem** is: what changes needs to be done on the `android` & the `C#`side to make sure only my app can scan it? In short a custom QR code.

Things I tried:
I have removed the version information from the QR code but unfortunately 4 out of 10 QR Scanners can scan it.

Comment: By definition, what you want is impossible. If your software can decode it, somebody else can write software to decode it.

Comment: scramble/encrypt your data in qr code

Comment: Wouldn't be more secure and reliable to just encrypt the data before writing the QR code? Of course you need to share the encryption key with your clients.

Comment: encoding and decoding will not work here. I don't want any other app to decode it.

Comment: @CommonsWare already explained the problem - whatever you do, someone else can work out what you did and do it to if they really want to

Comment: How did facebook and snapchat did ?

Comment: By using the already mentioned techniques.

Comment: Hi user3036123, I just edited your question. Please feel free to change back anything if I overdid it (e.g. the shorter title).

Comment: What techniques shall i use to achieve it ?